# How can I suppress a JSLint warning for a single line?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I use nicEdit editor, which has a function object called `nicEditor`.

JSLint puts a warning on it:

> A constructor name 'nicEditor' should start with an uppercase letter.

It ignores the  `/*jslint newcap:false */` option I put right before the troubled line"

```
/*jslint newcap:false */
var nic_editor = new nicEditor({
    buttonList : ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'emoticonToolbar'],
    iconsPath : '/assets/nicEditorIcons.gif'
}),
/*jslint newcap:true */
```

How can I suppress this warning but only for this line?

Comment: Can you switch to JSHint instead? This kind of thing is much easier with that.

Comment: I don't think I can switch easily 'cause I use JSLint through hallettj/jslint.vim Vim plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe its possible to be more finegrained than you currently are. And TBH, I think your current solution is just fine.

If you really want to avoid the `newCaps` setting you could just use a local variable to rename the constructor:

```
var NicEditor = nicEditor;
var nic_editor = new NicEditor({
    buttonList : ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'emoticonToolbar'],
    iconsPath : '/assets/nicEditorIcons.gif'
}),
```